# Memory dump debugging causes error in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, dump, xa

I am working with Windows Store applications development. When I try to debug my memory dumps, I am getting some exception which is completely new to me. Can you please anyone help me on this.

I am using VisualStudio 2013. I am using 3 PCL libraries with 4.5 higher framework. Can you please any one help me on this ?

[image]